# Extract digit after decimal in Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

How do you get the second digit from every float in a Numpy array?

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([[[1.93, 3.56],
                    [1.19, 0.35]],

                   [[0.51, 0.42],
                    [0.11, 1.55]],

                   [[4.43, 2.75],
                    [5.05, 2.12]]])
```

Using `np.trunc` I can obtain the first number:

```
np.trunc(array1)
array([[[1., 3.],
        [1., 0.]],

       [[0., 0.],
        [0., 1.]],

       [[4., 2.],
        [5., 2.]]])
```

But how do you get number after the decimal from `array1`? The result would look like:

```
array([[[9., 5.],
        [1., 3.]],

       [[5., 4.],
        [1., 5.]],

       [[4., 7.],
        [0., 1.]]])
```

Comment: I think you meant "second digit", so I corrected that.

Comment: this seem a math trick: multiply every element by ten, apply trunc, then apply module by 10.. can you code or do you need some further help?

Comment: @NicolasMartinez (and Bharath's answer) ohh I should've thought of that. Thanks. I feel dumb... the only way I thought of was converting to strings and taking the second element, which is an awful solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `mulitply by 10` and take the `remainder dividing by 10` i.e

```
(array1*10).astype(int)%10

array([[[9, 5],
        [1, 3]],

       [[5, 4],
        [1, 5]],

       [[4, 7],
        [0, 1]]])
```